# onChange is called only when the element loses focus

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onchange

I want that as you type in the textfield the div changes (I have the code for changing the div already). However the onchange event is only called once you are finished and click outside the textfield. I want it to be called as each letter is typed.

My code:

```
<input name="platetext" type="text" onchange="setValue(this)">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`onChange` is fired when the input looses focus I think. `onKeyUp` should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 4):

There is an 'input' Event you can bind your event Handlers to (I think this was introduced with HTML5).

I made a quick and very dirty example here: http://jsfiddle.net/RdKZH/

This would be the clean approach to this problem (as keyup does not work on copy&paste), but you might want to test if it already works in all browsers you want to support.

Comment: I tried you example changing the event to onkeyup and the copy&paste worked just nicely. Is there any hidden problem?

Comment: When pasting with Ctrl+V you're right, but if you use right click->paste it won't fire the keyup event (at least in most modern browsers).

Comment: That is correct, but if you add both onChange and onKeyUp it covers this scenario as well (tried chrome)

Comment: Yeah, I think that should work too. But since the input event is explicitly designed for this use case, I would still recommend using it. And maybe change or keyup as fallback for older browsers. Just my two cents. (:

Comment: @JanZyka
Here is yet another case: You press and hold a key to write the same character many times. The onChange and onKeyUp events won't fire every time a character is added. If you use the onChange and onKeyUp events to implement, for instance, a textarea with a limit on the character count and want to tell the user how many characters are left, it won't work with just onChange and onKeyUp because these won't update the count until the user releases the key. I just noticed this problem in the textarea from where I am writing this comment itself because this also has a character count limit.